# writing HTML back to file

Tags: html

Header for my input file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

After doing certain changes in document using lxml.html parser, i need to save the changes in a file. while doing so Header of the file changes to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"??>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

i am not sure why is this happening, may be its too silly but i am stuck here. please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe parser caters to the [IE6's Quirks mode triggering](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200904/using_an_xml_declaration_triggers_quirks_mode_in_ie_6/)?